# Python unable to update from thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm writing a third party plugin for another app. I need to run some code in a separate thread, but nothing run in a separate thread seems to get called.

Here's a basic example

```py
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from _Framework.ControlSurface import ControlSurface

class Collab(ControlSurface):
    def __init__(self, c_instance):
        ControlSurface.__init__(self, c_instance)

        # self.log_message is inherited from c_instance, logs
        # to the main app's log folder 
        self.log_message("COLLAB INIT")

        Thread(target=self.run_in_thread).start()
        self.log_message("Thread should run")
        sleep(5)
        self.log_message("Still waiting")
        sleep(5)

    def run_in_thread(self):
        sleep(1)
        self.log_message("Called from thread")
```

The output will be

```
COLLAB INIT
Thread should run
Still Waiting
```

`Called From thread` will never be logged.

I've tried every variation I can think of, I've tried locking the thread. I've tried running an infinite loop in the thread and verifying that the thread is still running (it is), I've tried modifying a shared global variable. Nothing run in a thread seems to be able to output anything, or effect any other variables.

Comment: Is *log\_message* inherited? How is the class instantiated?

Comment: What give a `print('Thread is running')` in `def run_in_thread(...`?